# Integrar componente Vue en angular

Tags: angular, vue.js

Tengo el componente de vue funcionando en otra app, quierp usar ese mismo componente en mi proyecto de angular pero estoy teniendo problemas

angular.json

```
   "scripts": [
     "src/assets/js/vuecomponent.umd.min.js",
     "src/assets/js/vue.js"
   ]
```

test-component.ts

```
import * as Vue from '../../assets/js/vue';
import * as vuecomponent from '../../assets/js/vuecomponent.umd.min';

showComponent(type: string) {
 let appModal = new Vue({
  el: "#fittingModal",
  data: { scenario: this.scenario, form: type
  },
  methods: {
    close : function() {
    },
  }
 })
}
```

test-component.html

```
<button pButton type="button" (click)="showComponent('loss')" label="Dist. Fitting"></button>
<div id="fittingModal">
    <fit-distribution :export="false"></fit-distribution>
</div>
```

Pero el error que me da cuando le doy al boton es:

```
Unknown custom element: <fit-distribution> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.
(found in <Root>)
```

Comment: Esto talvez ayude https://stackoverflow.com/a/49724561/4326551

Answer (score 0):

La recomendación es que evites al máximo hacer eso, no es una buena idea mezclar frameworks. Pero si tienes que hacerlo, podrías

1. Definir el vue component como un custom component

```
import { defineCustomElement } from 'vue'

const MyVueElement = defineCustomElement({
  // Definición de component
})

customElements.define('vue-element', MyVueElement)
```

2. Agrega al modulo donde lo vayas a utilizar `CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA`

```
 schemas: [
    CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA // Added for custom elements support
  ]
```

Esto permitirá que Angular no lance errores por no reconocer la etiqueta.

Importante, es necesario que utilices Vue 3.2